# Conditional formatting with xlR1C1 formula

Tags: vba, excel, type-conversion, conditional-formatting

Trying to apply conditional formatting via VBA to a spreadsheet that will have 25K+ rows. There isnt a set lastcolumn or last row so having difficulty applying the below code for some reason. When I check the condition formatting on each row it keeps referring to row 3 all the time. If I put RC" & lastCol +3 &"=FALSE" it recognises this as cell RC25 for example:

```
Range(Cells(3, FoundCol), Cells(lastrowRecon, FoundCol)).Select
   Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=R[]C" & lastCol + 3 & "=FALSE"
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 255
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> <sub>When I check the condition formatting on each row it keeps referring to row 3 all the time ... If I put RC" & lastCol +3 &"=FALSE" it recognises this as cell RC25 for example</sub>

RC25 is an xlA1 style cell reference. It is the 25th row in column RC .

You cannot put an xlR1C1 formula into a Conditional Formatting Rule when the Application.ReferenceStyle is xlA1; conversely, you cannot put an xlA1 style formula into a system currently running an xlR1C1 formula style. However, it is easy enough to flip between the two or use [Application.ConvertFormula](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822751.aspx) to switch the formula for you. There is no `Formula1R1C1` parameter to the .FormatConditions.Add method.

I think your xlR1C1 formula would be better as `"=NOT(RC" & (lastCol + 3) & ")"` .

```
Sub wqewqwew()
    Dim lastCol As Long, xlA1formula As String
    lastCol = 22
    With Selection
        .FormatConditions.Delete
        Application.ReferenceStyle = xlA1
        'when Application.ReferenceStyle = xlA1
        xlA1formula = Application.ConvertFormula("=NOT(RC" & (lastCol + 3) & ")", xlR1C1, xlA1, , .Cells(1))
        With .FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:=xlA1formula)
            .Interior.Color = 255
            .SetFirstPriority
        End With

        .FormatConditions.Delete
        Application.ReferenceStyle = xlR1C1
        'when Application.ReferenceStyle = xlR1C1
        With .FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=NOT(RC" & (lastCol + 3) & ")")
            .Interior.Color = 255
            .SetFirstPriority
        End With

        'switch back
        Application.ReferenceStyle = xlA1
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: In R1C1 style RC25 means column Y with the formula cell row. So if you put =RC25 in A1 that means in xlA1 style it is equivalent to $Y1.

Comment: @sktneer - Only if `Application.ReferenceStyle = xlR1C1`. If `Application.ReferenceStyle = xlA1` then `=RC25` means the 471st column, row 25.

Comment: Yeah absolutely correct. I was talking with the reference of question title only.

Comment: Yes, but that was the whole problem. ConditionalFormats.Add cannot add an xlR1C1 formula when the system is in xlA1 syntax mode. There is no Formula1R1C1 parameter. See my solution(s) above.

Comment: I agree with you here.

Answer (score 0):

lastcol hasn't been assigned a value so it's always going to be zero.

Likewise with lastrowrecon and FoundCol

Comment: Hi, Yes I have that in code further up. The conditional formula picks up the correct Col. Just having issues with the row. Below is the code i used to get lastCol:    lastCol = ActiveSheet.Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Comment: And the values are?

Comment: lastCol=25 in this case

Comment: And lastrowRecon and FoundCol?